# How to programmatically create multiple hyperlinks in a single Excel cell

Tags: c#, arrays, epplus

I am building an Excel Spreadsheet using EPPLUS:

I have a datatable for e.g.

CM     |     ID < columns

VW        |      23, 24, 25 < values

```
foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in ws2.Cells[2, 2, ToRow, 2])
{

    string new_cell;

    if (cell.Value == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {

        new_cell = cell.Value.ToString();
        string link = string.Empty;
        string hyperlink = string.Empty;
        string[] ints = new_cell.Split(',');

        cell.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
        {

            string s = ints[i];

            link = @"myapplication/viewCar/ID=" + s;

            cell.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(link) { Display = s };                             

        }
    }
}
```

so what the code does it takes the string as above: 23, 24, 25 comma separates it into an array and loops through, for each it generate a link and create a new cell.hyperlink. So, the issue i'm having is this:

```
cell.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(link) { Display = s };
```

it's only outputting the last element in the array, i know why because when it loops s = last element, what i don't know is how to fix the issue, not sure if this is possible aswell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `cell` never changes in the `for` loop. You're setting `cell.Hyperlink` several times on the same object, not on different objects. The last time you set it is the value it keeps. I'm not sure what you're even trying to do there.

Comment: Exactly. So is it possible to have it as i described?

Comment: Have what as who described where? I see no description of what you want. A cell has one `Hyperlink` property. This suggests that a cell can have only one hyperlink. If you want more than one hyperlink in a given cell, you have problems.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have each ID be a link to details page for that record. I can generate the link but as you say, the cell will only hold the last value i give it

Comment: change your for loop to a foreach loop or assign cell[i] what is the purpose of declaring `new_cell` there are much easier ways to loop thru and capture values from a split string or .csv file to assign to hyperlinks I would also learn some basics on C# and what happens inside of a loop have you even used the debugger..? or did you just `Write the code and Go`

Comment: @Ed Plunkett just seen your comment, right i thought this would be the case...

Comment: Here's a possible workaround, but it seems to me like it would be a huge hassle to do programmatically: https://superuser.com/a/982172/640841

Comment: Can you create a tooltip that pops up with arbitrary text in it, including multiple hyperlinks?

Comment: Good suggestion however, I've just tried this, it treats it as text.

Comment: I've put in a workaround, each ID now sits in a new cell and I've created a hyperlink within each cell